# Can't add new JDBC driver for Mongodb "Driver Class is missing"

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, jdbc, netbeans

**Context:**
I'm on Windows 10 using Netbeans IDE 8.1 .

I downloaded Hibernate OGM from sourceforge at this adress:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-ogm/5.3.1.Final/hibernate-ogm-5.3.1.Final-dist.zip/download

I then extracted all its files.

I found under `hibernate-ogm-5.3.1.Final\dist\lib\mongodb` the following files

[image: mongodbfiles]

I copied these files under my project's folder.

When I try to add a new driver in netbeans:
[image: Driver Class is missing]

I get the message/error `Driver Class is missing`...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MongoDB is not a relational database, and the driver jar is not a JDBC driver. You can't use JDBC with MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MongoDB Java driver is not a JDBC driver. That's the reason you cannot add it to Netbeans as such. This plugin should do what you are looking for: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52638/nbmongo

I've never used it though because I prefer to connect using the MongoDB client.

The JDBC standard is for relational databases and, at the moment, there isn't an equivalent for NoSQL databases. For this reason, Hibernate OGM uses its own dialect to connect to the datastore. The dialect will then use, underneath, the required library for the chosen db.

Comment: Should you decide to go down the path of a MongoDB JDBC driver, my company Progress DataDirect offers such a driver: https://www.progress.com/jdbc/mongodb . Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be interesting to see if it works with Hibernate ORM